# Can not generate code for Dual Core STM32H MCU on CubeMX

Tags: stm32

I have a problem to generate a code for MKD or IAR EWARM on CubeMX. I have a NUCLEO-H755ZI-Q development board.

I can generate the code for others MCU or Nucleo Botrads, but i have seen that this problem is only related to any MCU with dual core like STM32H755/745 and STM32H747. if I choose another card, the code generation is fine.

I have tried to reinstall all ( CubeMX, CubeIDE,MDK, downloading Packages..), all time the error message appears after code generating :

''the code is succesfully generated under [.....] but MDK-ARM 5.27 generation project but have a problem''.

I use the latest version of CubeMX : v6.0.1

Thank you for advance,

Answer (score 1):

I searched on the net and in the STM32 documentation, I found maybe a reason ;
in the St CubeMx Software requirements( UM1718 and RN0094) i find :

"The use of Java™ Runtime Environment (JRE) 64 bits is mandatory. JRE 32 bits is no more supported.
The JRE minimal version is 1.8_45. The version 1.8_251 must not be used (known Java issue).
Java 11 is supported. Java 7, Java 9, Java 10, Java 12 and upper are not supported."

I can finally generate the code by uninstalling all the Java SE and JDK versions that I had on my pc. I only installed Java JDK 11.0.9 64bit.

I can open the project, but there are still some errors during compilation because the project structure needs to be adjusted.